# how to prove $E(Y_n|B_n)\to E(Y_\infty|B_\infty)$

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, conditional-probability

Suppose $B_n\uparrow B_\infty$ and ${Y_n, n \in \bar{N}}$ is a sequence of random variables such that $Y_n \to Y_\infty$.

(a) If $|Y_n|\le Z \in L_1$, then show a.s. that
$$E(Y_n|B_n)\to E(Y_\infty|B_\infty).$$
(b) If $Y_n \to Y_\infty$ in $L_1$
$$E(Y_n|B_n)\to E(Y_\infty|B_\infty).$$

Easy forms, but hard for me to solve... any hints?

Comment: This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level. Upvoter: why the upvote?

Comment: @Did, Sorry, I didn't try hard before post it. I will work hard on the future questions and don't post it until the last minute..

Answer (score 0):

I will write $E_n[\cdot]$ for $E[\cdot | B_n]$ for convenience. Firstly note $Y_\infty \in L^1$. Define $Z_m = \sup_{r \geq m} |Y_r-Y_\infty|$. Note $Z_m \to 0$. We can then estimate $|E_nY_n - E_\infty Y_\infty| \leq |E_nY_n - E_n Y_\infty| + |E_n Y_\infty - E_\infty Y_\infty| \leq E_n Z_m + |E_n Y_\infty - E_\infty Y_\infty|$ for $m \leq n$.
Levy upward then tells us $\limsup |E_nY_n - E_\infty Y_\infty| \leq E_\infty Z_m$. Then since $|Z_m| \leq 2Y_\infty$ is dominated, we have $ |E_nY_n - E_\infty Y_\infty| \to 0$. This shows part (a).

For part (b) assume for contradiction that we do not have $E_n Y_n \to E_\infty Y_\infty$, say $|E_{n_k} Y_{n_k} - E_\infty Y_\infty| > \epsilon$ for all $n$. Then choose a subsequence $Y_{n'_k}$ of $Y_{n_k}$  on which we have a.s. convergence. By part (a) we will have $E_{n'_k} Y_{n'_k} \to E_\infty Y_\infty$, contradicting that $|E_{n_k} Y_{n_k} - E_\infty Y_\infty| > \epsilon$ for all $n$.

Comment: for the second part, we need to prove $L_1$ convengence, you seem to prove a.s.? By the way, when we say $Y_n \to Y_\infty$ in $L_1$, do we mean $Y_\infty \in L_1$?